# android: How to convert an int[] to an OpenCV Mat c++?

Tags: android, c++, opencv

Im trying to do some image processing using openCV on the array returned from onPreviewFrame(byte[] rawData), i have converted the byte array into int array.

my question is, how to convert this int array into Iplimage or Mat ?
will converting to the new Camera2 be any good?

i have tried this way to convert the array.

```
void ProcImage(int Width, int Height, int imageArray[]) {

cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(Width, Height, CV_32SC1 , imageArray);
}
```

but mat.data contains values like -14545898.
any solutions ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the Mat type `CV_32SC1` that you used.
You don't even have to convert the int array, and use the byte array as is

```
cv::Mat mat = new cv::Mat(Width, Height, CvType.CV_8UC3, byteArray);
```

where `byteArray` is your byte array.

If you still want to use the int array trying changing the type to one of `Mat: CV_32SC1，CV_32SC2，CV_32SC3，CV_32SC4` as specified in http://ninghang.blogspot.com/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html

Answer (score 0):

Directly in Java you could do something like this (it is based on the implementation of [JavaCameraView](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/android+JavaCameraView.java)):

```
...
Mat frameData = new Mat(frameHeight + (frameHeight/2), frameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera arg1) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Preview Frame received. Frame size: " + frame.length);
    synchronized (this) {
        frameData.put(0, 0, frame);
        ...
        this.notify();
    }
}

public Mat getRgbaFrame() {
    Mat rgba = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frameData, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
    return mRgba;
}

public Mat getGrayFrame() {
    return frameData.submat(0, frameHeight, 0, frameWidth);
}
```